# Program error-file in use in visual foxpro

Tags: forms, visual-foxpro, multi-table, file-in-use

i have to do some forms in visual fox pro 9 for a school project, and if i try to use multiple tables in one form occurs the error> file in use, even if i try to use the command "use thistable"           "use secondtable" before the code, then i can not close the form at all.
these are basically my codes in different command buttons but it doesn't work>

command1:

```
USE camera
SELECT camera.nr_camera, camera.ocupat, camera.tip_camera FROM camera WHERE camera.ocupat=.F.
```

command2:

```
USE rezervari
APPEND BLANK
replace id_rezerv WITH thisform.text1.value, id_client WITH thisform.text2.value, data_intrare WITH thisform.text3.Value, data_iesire WITH thisform.text4.value, nr_nopti WITH thisform.spinner1.value, nr_camera WITH thisform.spinner2.Value, mic_dejun WITH thisform.check1.Value

thisform.text1.Value=0

thisform.text2.Value=0

thisform.text3.Value=SPACE(20)

thisform.text4.Value=SPACE(20)

thisform.spinner1.Value=null

thisform.spinner2.Value=null

thisform.text1.SetFocus

thisform.Refresh
```

does anyone know what should i try? i even tried to use then close the table but it still won t work

Answer (score 2):

> command1: USE camera SELECT camera.nr_camera, camera.ocupat, camera.tip_camera FROM camera WHERE camera.ocupat=.F.

When you want to do an SQL`Select` in Vfp, you would Not need to use the `Use` command in advance. So your code could look simply like:

```
SELECT camera.nr_camera, camera.ocupat, camera.tip_camera ;
    FROM camera WHERE camera.ocupat=.F.
```

- And when you additionally `Set Exclusive Off` before you would open any table implicitly, as an SQL `Select` would do, then that implicitly opened "Alias" would get opened in Shared mode too.
  Where

> SET EXCLUSIVE is scoped to the current data session

See also the F1 Help chapter on that topic.

> command2: USE rezervari

When you want to open an `dBase/xBase` table in FoxPro programmatically, you'd normally do that in Shared mode, and inside the next unused so called work-area:

```
If Not Used("rezervari")
    Use rezervari In 0 Shared Again
Endif
```

... Where the `Use Again` means "even when that table is already `Used()` as another `Alias` name"

> APPEND BLANK replace id_rezerv WITH thisform.text1.value, id_client WITH thisform.text2.value, data_intrare WITH thisform.text3.Value, data_iesire WITH thisform.text4.value, nr_nopti WITH thisform.spinner1.value, nr_camera WITH thisform.spinner2.Value, mic_dejun WITH thisform.check1.Value

The code you posted is a little misaligned. You could however simplify the entire Use/Append Blank/ Replace sequence with a single SQL `Insert` line:

```
Insert Into rezervari ;
    (id_rezerv, id_client, data_intrare, data_iesire) ;
Values ( ;
    thisform.text1.value, ;
    thisform.text2.value, ;
    thisform.text3.Value, ;
    thisform.text4.value) && and so on
```

Even easier would be to add the desired table alias to the DataEnvironment of your Form, and then add string expressions like "rezervari.id_rezerv" to the `ControlSource` properties of your Controls in the VFP `Form Designer`. That way your `Form` and its `DataEnvironment` and its Controls would do all the work for you, much less code-behind required.
That's basically what the "Visual" in `visual-foxpro` is all about.